# Landscape installation Web GUI

Tags: apache2, landscape

I'm trying to install Landscape to a standalone server via `landscape-server-quickstart`.

Installation succeeds without any errors. I'm not able to access the Web UI from an external host though.

`lynx localhost` reveals the webserver is up and running and is showing the landscape UI.

I'm not an expert on Apache2 but I suspect the problem is related to SSL.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I also installed a x-server environment and can confirm the site works locally.

Answer (score 0):

If it works from your graphical session then it should work externally as well as it is accessible via page presented by apache.

Did you install landscape on your **(1)** local VM or **(2)** is it hosted somewhere in the cloud or DC?

**1)** run `ifconfig`  or `ifconfig | grep inet`
and from your laptop/desktop try to access IP that is being shown. You are looking for address that is shown after " inet addr:"

**2)** If its external then check for closed/open ports, both on your server:

```
sudo ufw status
```

and look for

```
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
```

and your firewall  \9software or physical) if you have in front of your server. Again, check IP as per suggestion **(1)** on your server that you installed landscape and try to access it first via IP rather then hostname if you set up any. 
Let me know if it worked, or if you need some more help.

Thanks
Bogdan